# Order by case in dbCommand.CommandText

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to add an order by case statement in the dbcommand.commandtext but i see that no rows are returned. I want to assign priorities for colors in the case statement. This would help me avoid create a new table to priorities and rewrite a lot of code to map the foreign key. Any inputs would be helpful.

Here's the statement:-

```
Protected Sub AddData()
    Dim cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))
    cn.Open()
    Dim dbCommand As New OleDbCommand
    dbCommand.Connection = cn

    dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from tblPosts ORDER BY CASE PriorityLevel WHEN 'Red' then 1 when 'Orange' then 2 ELSE 3 END"

    Try
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim objdatareader As OleDbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()
        While objdatareader.Read()
            Dim PostID As Integer = CInt(objdatareader("ID"))
            PopulateImages(PostID, cn)
            PopulateCategories(PostID, cn)
            rssFeed.AddItem(objdatareader, ImageList, CategoryList)
            ImageList.Clear()
            CategoryList.Clear()
        End While

        objdatareader.Close()
    Catch myerror As OleDbException
        Dim strErr As String = "There was an error updating the database: " & myerror.Message
    End
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any exceptions? I get a syntax error because you have `END PriorityLevel`. Removing `PriorityLevel` after the `END` does not bring any syntax errors.

Other than that, your statement looks correct.

This works:

```
declare @tblPosts table(
  PriorityLevel varchar(10)
  )

  insert into @tblPosts
  values('Orange'),('Red'),('Green'),('Orange')

  SELECT * from @tblPosts ORDER BY 
  CASE PriorityLevel WHEN 'Red' then 1 
                     when 'Orange' then 2 
  ELSE 3 END
```

This DOES NOT Work:

```
declare @tblPosts table(
  PriorityLevel varchar(10)
  )

  insert into @tblPosts
  values('Orange'),('Red'),('Green'),('Orange')

  SELECT * from @tblPosts ORDER BY CASE 
  PriorityLevel WHEN 'Red' then 1 
                when 'Orange' then 2 
  ELSE 3 END PriorityLevel
```

Comment: I do not get any syntax error. I have also tried removing the PriorityLevel at the end, but it returns no rows. I have tried replacing = 'Red' etc with like '%Red%'. Doesnt work :(

Comment: @PrathibhaAyyappan: Then your issue is that you don't have any data in your table. Run a straight select w/o the `order by` and confirm that you have data.

Comment: I do have data in my table. Without the order by i get back Red, Orange etc. as a result for the select statement.

Comment: I am passing the data to an xml file. Without the order by clause, here is part of the xml file...                                                                  **<category>|Pest Problems</category>
<image>
http://www.turfgrass.ncsu.edu/Images/Diseases/brownpatch/Thumbs300/brown%20patch.jpg
</image>
<PriorityLevel>Red</PriorityLevel>
<synopsis/>**

Comment: @PrathibhaAyyappan: So you are quering XML data... you need to specify those details on your question. Post the table schema, sample data and code on your question if you want people to be able to help you effectively.

Comment: @lcarus..I am fetching the data and creating an RSS Feed. I need to sort the RSS Feed based on the priority level. The priority level is a color in my attribute column. I am trying to assign priority using the order by case statement.

Comment: How do i add code here? I am a new user, please pardon my ignorance

Comment: @lcarus I have added the code to the question. I am sending the data from the sql to the rss feed. I need the priority level only to sort the order in which my feed appears.

Comment: @PrathibhaAyyappan: why are you using OleDBCommand on a Sql Server database?

Comment: This is tagged as sql-server. If you are querying a ms-access database, it used JET SQL, not TSQL. (Unless you are using an adp file, in which case the back end is MSSQL and the front end is MS-Access). What is the file extension of the ms-access bits you are using? (mdb or adp or accdb?) And are you using ODBC to link tables to SQL-Server or some other database?

Comment: I am using the SQL server database only for authentication purposes.    The rest of the data is in the MSAccess database. Thus, i need to query the MSAccess database and I read on some where that JET SQL does not support Case When clause. Is there any other way I can do this? or do I have no other choice but to create a new table for priorities ?